# How to to rescue from errors in a Rails template (ERB file)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an ERB template which has a few helper methods from other gems

`sample.html.erb`

```
<h1>All The Stuff</h1>
<% all_the_stuff.each do |stuff| %>
  <div><%= stuff %></div>
<% end %>
```

`lib/random_file.rb`

```
def all_the_stuff
   if ALL_THE_STUFF.exists?
      ALL_THE_STUFF
   else
      fail AllTheStuffException
   end
end
```

Now, if `ALL_THE_STUFF` were not not exist, I'll get an `ActionView::Template::Error`. However, that will not be caught be an exception handling at the controller level. 
In case of the controllers, I rescue exceptions in the `ApplicationController` using `rescue_from`. Is there a single place to put this for all my ERB templates?

How do I handle exceptions caught within a template (not due to controller code)?

Comment: `begin...rescue...end` works just fine in ERB.

Comment: I should've been clearer. In case of my application controller, I can do a `rescue_from` block to rescue, but there's no such place to do it for all the templates.

Comment: you should be able to do it the same way: rescue_from ActionView::Template::Error, with: :your_method_here

Answer (score 1):

I believe a better solution would be the following:

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  def sample
    @things = Thing.all
  end
end


# views/things/sample.html.erb
<h1>All The Things</h1>
<% if @things.present? %>
  <% @things.each do |thing| %>
    <div><%= thing %></div>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  There are no things at the moment.
<% end %>
```

This is the rails way and avoids using any `Exception` class as a control flow, which is usually a bad idea.